# Did God allowed Israelites to mistreat foreign slaves?

Tags: leviticus

> Your male and female slaves are to come from the nations around you; from them you may buy slaves.  You may also buy some of the temporary residents living among you and members of their clans born in your country, and they will become your property.  You can bequeath them to your children as inherited property and can make them slaves for life, but you must not rule over your fellow Israelites ruthlessly.
>    Leviticus 25:44-46

It seems that the phrase "you must not rule over your fellow Israelites ruthlessly" implies that Israelite masters can rule ruthlessly over non-Israelites (i.e. can mistreat them). No, believe it or not, to me, no verse before this last phrase are a problem, like " you can pass them on to your children and make them for life" as long as they are not allowed to be mistreated. However, last phrase SEEMS to imply they are mistreated, but Israelites can't be mistreated.

Does this really mean that foreign slaves can be mistreated? This phrase is the problem, so can someone explain it?

Comment: The text says that Israelites are not to be ruled over 'with rigour' (KJV and YLT]. The text does not (specifically) say that non-Israelites _are_ to be so treated.You are inferring that, but it is not there in the text.

Comment: But that phrase appears after talking about non-Israelite slaves, and it says ,,but you cannot rule over Israelites with rigour". That doesn't say non-Israelite slaves are treated with rigour directly, but it does IMPLY they are, otherwise, why would it say ,,but don't rule over your fellow Israelites with rigour"?

Comment: You are inferring it. The text (in my view) is not implying it.

Comment: But why would it be aded ,,but do not rule over Israelites ruthlessly" if non-Israelites are not mistreated?

Answer (score 1):

1. > <sup>48</sup>And when a stranger shall sojourn with thee, and will keep the passover to the LORD, let all his males be circumcised, and then let him come near and keep it; and he shall be as one that is born in the land: for no uncircumcised person shall eat thereof.
   >   
   > <sup>49</sup>**One law shall be to him that is homeborn, and unto the stranger that sojourneth among you.**
   > *-- Exodus 12:48-49 (KJV)*
2. > <sup>9</sup>Also **thou shalt not oppress a stranger**: for ye know the heart of a stranger, seeing ye were strangers in the land of Egypt.
   > *-- Exodus 23:9 (KJV)*
3. > <sup>33</sup>And if a stranger sojourn with thee in your land, ye shall not vex him. <sup>34</sup>But **the stranger that dwelleth with you shall be unto you as one born among you, and thou shalt love him as thyself**; for ye were strangers in the land of Egypt: I am the LORD your God.
   >   
   > *-- Leviticus 19:33-34 (KJV)*
4. > <sup>35</sup>And if thy brother be waxen poor, and fallen in decay with thee; then thou shalt relieve him: **yea, though he be a stranger, or a sojourner**; that he may live with thee.
   >   
   > *-- Leviticus 25:35 (KJV)*
5. > <sup>16</sup>Circumcise therefore the foreskin of your heart, and be no more stiffnecked. <sup>17</sup>For the LORD your God is God of gods, and Lord of lords, a great God, a mighty, and a terrible, which regardeth not persons, nor taketh reward: <sup>18</sup>He doth execute the judgment of the fatherless and widow, and loveth the stranger, in giving him food and raiment.
   > <sup>19</sup>**Love ye therefore the stranger**: for ye were strangers in the land of Egypt.
   > *-- Deuteronomy 10:16-19 (KJV)*

The Law makes it abundantly clear that foreigners who joined themselves to Israel, i.e. those who committed themselves to life under the Law, were to be considered as "homeborn/ones born among you" and "brothers", and as such they were not to be oppressed nor afflicted.

If one were hard hearted/stiffnecked, then they might be inclined to argue that strangers/foreigners who didn't adopt the requirements of the Law could be oppressed, but I'm pretty sure they'd have a hard time justifying such behaviour before the LORD.

#### Conclusion

The Law strictly forbids Israel from mistreating foreigners.

Comment: This is a good answer - I wouldn't bother writing one to compete with it. However, I think it is worth considering the 'norms' of the nations around Israel at the time (indeed, the whole country were descended from ex-slaves). Israel was the first nation to codify any kind of laws protecting the life or rights of slaves, and so when it says not to rule over Israelites ruthlessly, I'd suggest the intended implication wasn't to imply permission of abusing others, but rather the strength is on the prohibition of mistreatment towards their brothers.

Comment: Thanks, @SteveTaylor. Hebrews 4:12 speaks of the word of God being a two edged sword, and it's so right. What people see as implications in the word, e.g. `"you must not rule over your fellow Israelites ruthlessly" implies that Israelite masters can rule ruthlessly over non-Israelites (i.e. can mistreat them)`, speaks volumes about the heart of one who sees such an implication -- how it is at odds with the heart of the LORD. I make that statement as an observation, not a judgement.